# Nginx how to mask url with proxy_pass or add location to url

Tags: nginx

I'm having some trouble making a url while I pass the request off to an upstream server.

Basically, the webapp on an upstream server that I am trying to setup has to exist at the location example.com/web.  I can not change it.  I have everything working except rewriting the url example.com  to example.com/web.

I would ideally love to mask the /web part so the user only sees example.com but I will be happy with at least getting Nginx to automatically add the /web for the user.  Currently I have to manually add /web to the url to get to the app.

My current config is:

```
  upstream app {
      server x.x.x.x:port;
  }

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name example.com;

      location / {
          try_files $uri @backend;
      }

      location @backend {
          proxy_pass http://app;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
      }
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [the official documentation for the `http_rewrite_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) of NGINX.

There are lots of example doing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: URI masking is different from rewriting url.